# C - Confusion over arrays and strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

Im sort of new to programming and I really get confused between strings and arrays. According to what I've read online and in my book a string can only hold char's (letters and not numbers) and arrays can hold only ints ( numbers and not letters). Is my concept of these wrong?

Comment: Arrays can hold anything (any object at least; an array of functions doesn't work).

Comment: In C, strings are just arrays of characters, i.e `char []`.

Comment: @chris You can have arrays of pointers to function : `void (*tab[])()`

Comment: As string is simply a special case of an array; it is an array of characters terminated by a null byte, `'\0'`.  There are various sub-species of strings (Unicode, wide character, etc), but they're a problem for later.

Comment: @Unda, Yes, that was just an example for arrays not being able to store *anything*.

Comment: Understand that neither an array nor a string is real, but arrays are a little bit realer than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept is wrong.
In c there is no strings as data type. String is an array of elements, which can represent character. As old ascii table contains only 256 characters chars (8-bit unsigned numbers) are used. First 0 number in array is interpreted as end of string. Each number in array denotes to symbol according to ascii code page.

```
char a[10] = {'o', 'n', 'e', '\0'};
char b[10] = {111, 110, 101, 0};
```

Here a and b are equal. You can do also

```
int x = a[0];
```

and x will keep 'o' character which is number 111. So

```
printf("%d", a[0]);
```

will output 111, and

```
printf("%c", a[0]);
```

will print o. As it is numbers, you can compare characters

```
if ('o' > 'A')
```

is truth, because (int) 'o' == 111 and (int) 'A' == 65. But 8-bit is too few to keep many different characters. So, other types can be used to keep character, wchar_t is popular for unicode, for example. So, string can be an array of wchar_t, or int, or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try these out, should clear up all your current / future doubts.

Arrays : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure

Strings : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29

Comment: link only answers are discouraged and may get flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a sequence of values, where the values can be of any type. You can have an array of integers:

```
int a[10]; // an array of 10 integers
```

an array of double precision floating point numbers:

```
double b[10]; // an array of 10 doubles
```

an array of pointers to integers:

```
int *c[10]; // an array of 10 pointers
```

an array of 10 characters:

```
char d[10]; // an array of 10 characters
```

and so on. The types can be more complex, too -- you can have arrays of structs, etc.

C doesn't have a built-in type specifically for strings -- strings are just arrays of characters. By convention, and in order to be compatible with a whole lot of existing C code, strings in C are null terminated, i.e. they end with a character with value 0, `'\0'`. When people talk about "C strings" or "strings" in the context of C programming, they mean null-terminated sequence of characters. A string doesn't necessarily have to be created as an array (like `char e[255]`) -- it might be created using a function like `malloc()` instead, but since an array is just a contiguous list of values you get the same result either way.

Answer (score 0):

- In **C** string can be store as array of characters only. There is no other way of storing the string.
- In **arrays** you can store any data type like Integers, Floats ,Characters or more.
- Arrays of character can be treated as strings on which you can apply operations according you.
- In string last character is '\0'(**null character**) which shows that string has been ended.

  For example

  `int array[10];   //array of 10 ints
  char string[10];   //string or character array of length 10
  float aa[10];     //It can stores 10 float values`

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

In `C` a `string` IS an `array` containig `chars`.

When you say *"an array not can contains only `int`"* you are not totally right. An array can contains only a type of data not only integers;

```
int a[] =    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};     // Array of ints
double b[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5}; // Array of doubles
char[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; // Array of chars, also called string.
```

Comment: last one is NOT a string as it is not null terminated

Comment: @zoska, the last one actually -is- a 'string'.  Perhaps it is an improperly terminated 'C string', but it still qualifies as a 'string' of characters.

Comment: Yes, but as OP is very inexperienced, this example could make some harm. It should be clearly marked that C string is null terminated, because every function from C api which operates on strings expect this null termination.

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that the term 'string' evolved from the term 'string of char'.  A good definition of 'string of char' might be "A number of char values found adjacent to each other in memory".

What are possible 'char values'? Consider the initialization of following `char arrays`:

```
char array1[8] = {77, 97, 104, 111, 110, 114, 105, 0};
char array2[8] = {0x4D, 0x61, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x72, 0x69, 0x00};
char array3[8] = {'\x4D', '\x61', '\x68', '\x6F', '\x6E', '\x72', '\x69', '\x00'};
char array4[8] = {'M', 'a', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'r', 'i', '\0'};
char array5[8] = "Mahonri";
```

Can any of the above be classified as a 'string of char'? Of course.  They all are both 'strings of char' as well as 'arrays of char'.  These terms are interchangeable.

Now consider the following:

```
int string1[8] = {77, 97, 104, 111, 110, 114, 105, 0};
int string2[8] = {0x4D, 0x61, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x72, 0x69, 0x00};
int string3[8] = {'\x4D', '\x61', '\x68', '\x6F', '\x6E', '\x72', '\x69', '\x00'};
int string4[8] = {'M', 'a', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'r', 'i', '\0'};
int string5[8] = {L"Mahonri"};
```

The above are 'strings of int', or 'int arrays'.  Perhaps this is hard to swallow for those who associate the term 'string' to the 'char' type.  Nevertheless, this is a proper use of both the term 'string' and 'array'.

Hence, it is not improper to refer to 'string of *{any type}*', as it is also proper to refer to an 'array of *{any type}*'.

So, as to the statement: `...A string can only hold char's (letters and not numbers) and arrays can hold only ints ( numbers and not letters).`

I am inclined to call this statement 'nonsense'.

---

That being said; the term 'string' has been coined to mean 'string of char', as well as 'C string'. A good definition of a 'C string' might be "A number of char values found adjacent to each other in memory, where the value of the last relevant char in the string is generally zero".

Can a 'C string' be termed 'an array of char'?  Yes.

---

So, the term 'string' by itself is actually ambiguous.  Perhaps it would be more unambiguous to use the terms 'C string' or 'string of char'.  However, both of these terms can be referred to as 'array of char'.

The confusion demonstrated in the question is in looking for a difference between 'string' and 'array', when in reality, there is no difference.